# Visual Studio - testEnvironments.json - how to configure docker run?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, unit-testing

As per MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022), the `testEnvironments.json` can be used for running unit tests in a docker container.

My `testsEnvironments.json` looks as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "1",
    "environments": [
      {
        "name": "debian-net6",
        "type": "docker",
        "dockerFile": "./testsDockerfile"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Everything works as expected - my unit tests can be executed in a docker container. Now I would like to configure how the actual container is created. For instance, I would like to mount a docker socket, using `docker run -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ....` or mount other volumes explicitly.

The Visual Studio creates the container (if not running) behind-the-scenes and mounts the solution directory whenever the unit tests are executed. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way how to customize how the container is created.

I am aware of other options, such as running a remote machine or a local WSL distribution, but I am interested mostly in this dockerFile/dockerImage approach.

From what I was able to gather, it seems to me that this sort of configuration is not supported right now (this testsEnvironment.json feature is still in experimental preview). I have also looked into `.runsettings` file, but it does not seem to offer anything of interest.